# Implications of unused bindings in a `VkDescriptorSetLayout`?

Tags: c++, performance, vulkan

I have two fragment shaders (written in GLSL), both with an array of samplers. The other bindings are identical, however, the array is different sizes between the two:

```
layout (binding = 2) uniform sampler2D tex[2];
```

vs

```
layout (binding = 2) uniform sampler2D tex[4];
```

I can create a `VkDescriptorSetLayout` with a `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding` matching this parameter:

```
VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding parameter;
memset(&parameter, 0, sizeof(VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding));
parameter.binding = 2;
parameter.descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER;
parameter.descriptorCount = 4;
parameter.stageFlags = VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT;
// go on to call vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout with this VkDescriptorSetBinding (and others)
```

The created `VkDescriptorSetLayout` will function correctly for binding to both shaders.

**Two questions:**

Is the only implication of the unused descriptors that any `VkDescriptorSet` will be larger than necessary (in the case of the first shader's array)? 
Are the extra allocated descriptors a large performance and/or memory concern?

Comment: To clarify, you want to understand the potential difference between what you have now and a case where you give each pipeline a *separate* layout, yes? So your question would be about the cost of layout changes when you're already going to change the pipeline *and* descriptor set, relative to the added memory of having a less-pipeline-specific layout.

Comment: @NicolBolas yes, exactly.